# How to get a published collection's total count, regardless of a specified limit, on the client?

Tags: meteor

I'm using the [meteor-paginated-subscription](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-paginated-subscription) package in my app.  On the server, my publication looks like this:

```
Meteor.publish("posts", function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {
    limit: limit
  });
});
```

And on the client:

```
this.subscriptionHandle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination("posts", 10);

Template.post_list.events = {
  'click #load_more': function(event, template) {
    template.subscriptionHandle.loadNextPage();
  }
};
```

This works well, but I'd like to hide the #load_more button if all the data is loaded on the client, using a helper like this:

```
Template.post_list.allPostsLoaded = function () {
  allPostsLoaded = Posts.find().count() <= this.subscriptionHandle.loaded();
  Session.set('allPostsLoaded', allPostsLoaded);
  return allPostsLoaded;
};
```

The problem is that Posts.find().count() is returning the number of documents loaded on the client, not the number available on the server.

I've looked through the [Telescope](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope) project, which also uses the meteor-paginated-subscription package, and I see [code](https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/client/views/posts/posts_list.js) that does what I want to do:

```
allPostsLoaded: function(){
  allPostsLoaded = this.fetch().length < this.loaded();
  Session.set('allPostsLoaded', allPostsLoaded);
  return allPostsLoaded;  
}
```

But I'm not sure if it's actually working.  Porting their code into mine does not work.

Finally, it does look like Mongo supports what I want to do. The [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/) say that, by default, cursor.count() ignores the effects of limit.

Seems like all the pieces are there, but I'm having trouble putting them together.

Comment: What is the difference between what you are asking and the "counts-by-room" [example in docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)?

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers do what you really want becase none provide solution that is reactive.

This package does exactly what you want and also reactive.

[publish-counts](https://github.com/percolatestudio/publish-counts)

Answer (score 6):

I think you can see the demo: [counts-by-room](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) in meteor doc

It can help you publish the counts of your posts at server and get it at client

You can simply write this:

```
// server: publish the current size of your post collection
Meteor.publish("counts-by-room", function () {
  var self = this;
  var count = 0;
  var initializing = true;

  var handle = Posts.find().observeChanges({
    added: function (id) {
      count++;
      if (!initializing)
        self.changed("counts", 'postCounts', {count: count});
    },
    removed: function (id) {
      count--;
      self.changed("counts", postCounts, {count: count});
    }

  });

  initializing = false;
  self.added("counts", 'postCounts', {count: count});
  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});

// client: declare collection to hold count object
Counts = new Mongo.Collection("counts");

// client: subscribe to the count for posts
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe("postCounts");
});

// client: simply use findOne, you can get the count object
Counts.findOne()
```

Answer (score 4):

The idea of `sub.loaded()` is to help you with exactly this problem.

`Posts.count()` isn't going to return the right thing because, as you've guessed, on the client, Meteor has no way of knowing the real number of posts that live on the server. But what the client knows is **how many posts it's *tried* to load**. That's what that `.loaded()` tells you, and is why the line `this.fetch().length < this.loaded()` will tell you if there are more posts on the server or not.

Comment: It will not work in case if total cursor count will be exactly the same as this.loaded(). Then you'll have to press "Load More" button one more time in order for this function to return true;

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is write a Meteor server side method that retrieves the count like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getPostsCount: function () {
        return Posts.find().count();
    }
});
```

Then call it on the client, in observe to make it reactive:

```
function updatePostCount() {
    Meteor.call('getPostsCount', function (err, count) {
        Session.set('postCount', count); 
    });
}
Posts.find().observe({
    added: updatePostCount,
    removed: updatePostCount
});
```

Comment: `Posts.find().observe()` on client will not know when `Posts.find().count()` changes on the server if the client is subscribed to a subset of posts.

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old, I thought I would provide an answer that ended up working for me. I did not create the solution, I found the basis for it here (so credit where credit is due): [Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828387)

Anyway, in my case I was trying to get "size" of the database from client side, so I can determine when to hide the "load more" -button. I was using template level subscriptions. Oh and for this solution to work, you need to add reactive-var -package. Here is my (in short):

```
/*on the server we define the method which returns
 the number of posts in total in the database*/

if(Meteor.isServer){
  Meteor.methods({
    postsTotal: function() {
    return PostsCollection.find().count();
    }
  });
}


/*In the client side we first create the reactive variable*/

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.Posts.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.totalPosts = new ReactiveVar(); 
  });


  /*then in my case, when the user clicks the load more -button,
  we call the  postsTotal-method and set the returned value as 
  the value of the totalPosts-reactive variable*/

  Template.Posts.events({
    'click .load-more': function (event, instance){
        Meteor.call('postsTotal', function(error, result){
            instance.totalPosts.set(result);
        });
    }
  });

}
```

Hope this helps someone (I recommend checking the link first). For template level subscriptions, I used this as my guide [Discover Meteor - template level subscriptions.](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/) This was my first stacked-post and I am just learning Meteor, so please have mercy...:D

Answer (score 1):

Ouch this post is old, anyway maybe it will help someone. 
I had exactly the same issue. I managed to solve it with 2 simple lines...
Remember the :

```
handle = Meteor.subscribeWithPagination('posts', 10);
```

Well I used in client `handle.loaded()` and `Posts.find().count()`. Because when they are different it means that all the posts are loaded. So here is my code :

```
"click  #nextPosts":function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    handle.loadNextPage();
    if(handle.loaded()!=Posts.find().count()){
        $("#nextPosts").fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and using the publish-counts package didn't work with the subs-manager package. I created a package that can set a reactive server-to-client session, and keep the document count in this session. You can find an example here:

https://github.com/auweb/server-session/#getting-document-count-on-the-client-before-limit-is-applied

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something like this:

**On cliente**

```
Template.postCount.posts = function() {
    return Posts.find();
};
```

Then you create a template:

```
<template name="postCount">
  {{posts.count}}
</template>
```

Then, whatever you want to show the counter: *{{> postCount}}*

Much easier than any solution i have seen.

Comment: This is useless because in a real world application you will never load all the database on the client, and the code you proposed count all posts loaded on the client. Using Meteor.call() and Meteor.methods() is the right way because the count is computed on the server.

Comment: and if you use Meteor.methods it doesnt become reactive. what do you return in the server method. ```return Posts.find().count()``` ?